# Code to copy, paste and summarize a data set

Tags: vba, excel

The code currently works as it should and seems to work dynamically as I need it to but I am pretty new to Excel so I think there is probably a better way to do some of the things I have set up. I also would like to make the code a bit prettier.

```
'*******************************************************************************************************************************
'*******************This finds, copies, and moves the data to the correct sheets then formats them correctly********************
'*******************************************************************************************************************************

Sub Copy_Function_Data()
Dim Target As String
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim Target_2 As String
Dim Last_Row3 As Long
Dim Last_Column3 As Long
Dim Total_Count As Long
Dim Title_Column As Long
Dim Country_Column As String
Dim Row_Limit1, Row_Limit2 As Long
Dim Column_Limit1 As Long
Dim Row_Limit3 As Long
Dim Current_Sheet As String
Dim r As Range
Dim r2 As Range


Application.StatusBar = "Moving Data..."

Y = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3", Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For X = 1 To Y

Sheets("Calculations").Select
Target = Range("B2").Offset(X, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "TempData"
Worksheets("TempData").Range("A1").Value = Target
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Open Position - ", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Target_2 = Worksheets("TempData").Range("A1")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = (Target_2)
Sheets("Raw Data").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$Z$10000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    (Target)
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(Target_2).Select
Range("B50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Total_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("B50", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("B50").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Last_Row3 = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row
Last_Column3 = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
            After:=Range("A1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column
Title_Column = Cells.Find(What:="Title", _
            After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False).Column
Country_Column = Cells.Find(What:="Country", _
            After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False).Column
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("R51", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("R51").End(xlDown)).Rows.Copy
Range("X50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Range("$X$50:$X$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlNo
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("X50") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Sort
    .SetRange Range("X50:X10000")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Row_Limit1 = Worksheets(Target_2).Range("X:X").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

If Row_Limit1 > 1 Then


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("X50", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("X50").End(xlDown)).Rows.Copy
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Else
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("X50", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("X50")).Copy
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("V51", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("V51").End(xlDown)).Rows.Copy
Range("Y50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Range("$Y$50:$Y$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlNo
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Y20") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Sort
    .SetRange Range("Y50:Y10000")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Row_Limit2 = Worksheets(Target_2).Range("Y:Y").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

If Row_Limit2 > 1 Then

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("Y50", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("Y50").End(xlDown)).Rows.Copy

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Else
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Target_2).Range("Y50", Worksheets(Target_2).Range("Y50")).Copy
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("TempData").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    Cells.Find(What:="Title", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Name = "Range1"
            Set r = Range("Range1")
    Cells.Find(What:="Country", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Name = "Range2"
            Set r2 = Range("Range2")

Row_Limit1 = Worksheets(Target_2).Range("X:X").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Column_Limit1 = Worksheets(Target_2).Range("Y:Y").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
With Worksheets(Target_2)
.Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(Row_Limit1 + 2, Column_Limit1 + 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & r.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",RC2, " & r2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",R2C)"
.Range(.Cells(Row_Limit1 + 3, 3), .Cells(Row_Limit1 + 3, Column_Limit1 + 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R3C:R[-1]C)"
End With



Next X



 Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about the problem your code is solving? Where is your data, What is your data, Do you have any control over where/how it is entered, Do you have any control over where/how it needs to be output? Are there any other specific requirements?

Comment: The data is in a sheet called "Raw Data" and it is currently in the same format each time the report is pulled. It comes from an Essbase pull. I have left instructions on the sheet to always ensure that the data lines up with the current template and that headers be normalized to the defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **first** thing I would address is using `.Select` or `.Activate` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow addressing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros.

First thing to do would be to give some variables to your worksheets

```
Dim calcSheet as worksheet
set calcSheet = Thisworkbook.sheets("Calculations")
Dim rawSheet as worksheet
set rawSheet = thisworkbook.sheets("raw data")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "tempdata"
dim tempSheet as worksheet
set tempsheet = thisworkbook.sheets("tempdata")
```

You get the idea. Now everytime you need to work with a selection, just specify the sheet object instead. Also, worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mySheet")` and instead just use `mySheet`.

So for example, this -

```
For X = 1 To Y
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Target = Range("B2").Offset(X, 0)
```

Becomes this

```
For x = 1 to Y
    Target = calcSheet.cells(2+x,2)
```

Easy peasy!

---

So this

```
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(Target_2).Select
Range("B50").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Becomes this simple

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastColumn = rawSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = rawSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
secondTarget.Range(Cells(50, 2), Cells(50 + lastRow, 2 + lastColumn)) = rawSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1 + lastRow, 2 + lastColumn)).Value
```

You'll notice I changed the method of finding the bounds. There is a [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1161309) way to find lastRow and lastColumn. That post explains why.

---

In this loop, you're creating a sheet *everytime*

```
For X = 1 To Y

Sheets("Calculations").Select
Target = Range("B2").Offset(X, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```

Make the sheet before the loop and if you need to, just clear it before the next iteration.